# Inconsistent output from Range.TextToColumns after it is used once

Tags: excel, vba

I paste a range from another application that has spaces in each line.

I use `Range.TextToColumns` to separate the output to separate columns.  It works once. The next time I copy the range it is already separated into the columns. The result is inconsistent output.

I could add an `IF` to get around it, but that would be ugly.  Some parameter is getting set and affecting the second iteration.  I would like to reset that parameter at the top of my code, but I haven't been able to find what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In the object browser search for TextToColumns, highlight it in the Members pane then hit F1. That will take you to the MS help on the topic that has all of the parameters.

Comment: The descriptions for those parameters do not relate to the actual issue. When I first use texttocolumn in my macro the entire line pastes into the first column, spaces and all.  Every time after that, even in different sheets and different workbooks, the data pastes into the multiple columns.  I need to close Excel to get back to the whole line pasted into the first column.  This is something getting set/saved at the Excel level, not the macro level.

Comment: Ahh. My mistake. What needs doing is to reset the TextToColumns itself. Put some data in a cell and do TextToColumns in a way that nothing happens.

Comment: When I do a sort in VBA I enter this command first: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear to be sure the sort starts with all fields at default.  I need something comparable for the TexttoColumn command.

Comment: Thanks, but no it didn't. Same as before.  1st run, all of the pasted line goes into the 1st cell.  Ran the above subroutine and when I pasted the line it was parsed over six cells based on "space" as a delimiter as in the previous run.  Close Excel and it goes back to pasting all into the first cell.

Comment: So that I am clear. You do the initial paste and no `TextToColumns` action is taken by Excel. You then do a `Range.TextToColumns`. Then you call `ResetText2ColumnsDelimiter()`. Then you do a copy and paste of some other info and it does an automatic `TextToColumns`?

Comment: I think the way you've stated it is accurate.  The inconsistency occurs when I paste the data into the spreadsheet.  When I paste the data in for the first time, the entire line goes into the first cell.  I use texttocolumn to parse it across five cells  macro completes, no issue.  The next time I past the data in it is parsed across the five cells without running texttocolumn.  The inconsistency makes reusing the macro problematic.

Comment: To get back to the point where the entire line pasts into the first cell (and requires the texttocolumn) is to close all Excel windows, running the ResetText2ColumnsDelimiter() routine before the 2nd paste did not change the result.

Answer (score 0):

An Example From: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/70907-reset-text-to-columns-delimiter-in-vba

```
Sub ResetText2ColumnsDelimiter()

    Dim rngEmptyCell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngEmptyCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1, 1)
    rngEmptyCell.Value = "ABC"
    rngEmptyCell.TextToColumns Destination:=rngEmptyCell, _
                               DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                               ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                               Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                               Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    rngEmptyCell.Clear

End Sub
```